# Python nested while loop issues

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

I am relatively new to coding and I am doing a project where I make a game which is similiar to battleships e.g. 2 players place 10 ships on a 'board' and I have made a 2d array for each player where 0 = no ship and 1 = ship. I have made it so that the first player has to input an x and y value for each ship from 0-7 and if they do not input from 0-7 it is in a while loop so it keeps asking them to input a value from 0-7. I would also like to make it so that if a set of coordinates has already got a ship on it, then it asks the player to input a new set of coordinates. However, I'm having trouble with the nested while loop.

The problem:

**When I run this, and I input the 2 same coordinates, it repeats "You already have a tank placed here. Please input another set of coordinates.". I think when it runs through the outer loop it maybe skips the inner while loops also?**

```
p1Board = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
flag3 = True
flag4 = True
var1 = True

#Player 1 Tank 2 
while var1 == True:
  while flag3 == True:
    p1XCoordTank2 = int(input("\nOn which x-coordinate would you like to place your second tank? "))
    flag3 = False
    if p1XCoordTank2 < 0 or p1XCoordTank2 > 7:
      print("Please choose an x-coordinate that is in the range 0-7. ")
      flag3 = True
  while flag4 == True:
    p1YCoordTank2 = int(input("On which y-coordinate would you like to place your second tank? "))
    flag4 = False
    if p1YCoordTank2 < 0 or p1YCoordTank2 > 7:
      print("Please choose an y-coordinate that is in the range 0-7. ")
      flag4 = True
  if p1Board[p1XCoordTank2][p1YCoordTank2] == 1:
    print("You already have a tank placed here. Please input another set of coordinates. ")
    var1 = True
```

Not sure how to fix it. Please may I get some help.

Comment: Please be more specific than "I'm having trouble with the nested while loop" in your error description. Include all debugging details. What's the expected output/behavior for a given input? What's the actual output? Is there an error message?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time using stackoverflow. Hopefully I've edited it in more detail this time.

Comment: I would advise to make your variables more explanatory, `p1Board` explains what the variable holds (could be renamed to p1_board, to match snake casing). `flag3`, `flag4` and `var1` do not. It makes the code easier to read for yourself, but especially for others.

Comment: If the coordinate has already got a ship placed there, then p1Board[p1XCoordTank2][p1YCoordTank2] == 1. It should set var1 back to True and I would've thought that it would have gone through the whole section of code again, asking the user to input the coordinates of the second tank again. However, it just repeats the same string.

Comment: @Paul, what could I do to the flag3 etc variables? I thought that they're conditional variables so I could just do what I did? But from now on I'll use snake case for readability.

Comment: Performance-wise, it doesn't matter what the variables are called. However, giving variables explanatory names makes it much more readable. see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions.

Comment: You could rename `flag3`, for example, to `x_coordinate_set`

Comment: @Paul, Ah, I understand what you mean now. Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, I cannot reproduce your error. When I enter the same coordinate for X and Y (f.e. 0, 0) I do not get the You already have a tank placed here. Please input another set of coordinates. message.
However, the while loop keeps running, because there is no way in you code var1 will be set to False. 
Add:
  `else: var1 = False`

Comment: @Paul, I think it doesn't get the same error because I didn't include the section of code before which sets the coordinates for Tank1 as 1. I wasn't sure whether to include it since the main problem was in this section of code, I'll edit it now

Comment: @yrntakeoff Not seeing any edits, but did my answer solve your question? If so, please 'Accept as answer' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error where the message:

```
You already have a tank placed here. Please input another set of coordinates.
```

is printed when entering the same coordindates (f.e. p1XCoordTank2 = 0 , p1YCoordTank2 = 0).

However, to stop you while loop from running, you have to set var1 to False somewhere:

```
flag3 = True
flag4 = True
var1 = True

#Player 1 Tank 2 
while var1 == True:
  while flag3 == True:
    p1XCoordTank2 = int(input("\nOn which x-coordinate would you like to place your second tank? "))
    flag3 = False
    if p1XCoordTank2 < 0 or p1XCoordTank2 > 7:
      print("Please choose an x-coordinate that is in the range 0-7. ")
      flag3 = True
  while flag4 == True:
    p1YCoordTank2 = int(input("On which y-coordinate would you like to place your second tank? "))
    flag4 = False
    if p1YCoordTank2 < 0 or p1YCoordTank2 > 7:
      print("Please choose an y-coordinate that is in the range 0-7. ")
      flag4 = True
  if p1Board[p1XCoordTank2][p1YCoordTank2] == 1:
    print("You already have a tank placed here. Please input another set of coordinates. ")
    var1 = True
  else:
    p1Board[p1XCoordTank2][p1YCoordTank2] = 1 #place the tank
    var1 = False #stop the while loop
```